# "Cannot find module" with NestJS

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, nestjs

So, I have my `RootModule`, a `ProductModule` and a `StoreModule`.

My RootModule:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ProductModule,
    StoreModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class RootModule {}
```

My ProductModule:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [ProductService],
  exports: [],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

My StoreModule:

```js
@Module({
  imports: []
  providers: [StoreService, StoreWaitingService],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

1. Since my `RootModule` imports ProductModule, shouldn't I be able to use `ProductService` on `StoreService` and `StoreWaitingService`?
2. What if I imported ProductModule on `StoreModule` imports?

Comment: read the docs https://docs.nestjs.com/modules It should clarify about `1`. Also, you can import `ProductModule` on `StoreModule` as well, you just need to understand what that `exports` array mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Product Module and Service in StoreService

***Product Module***

```
@Module({
  providers: [ProductService],
  exports: [ProductService],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

***Store Module***

```
@Module({
  imports: [ProductModule],
})
export class StoreModule{}
```

***Store service***

```
import ProductService from '<Product Service Path>';
...

constructor(private readonly productService: ProductService){}

...
//in Function
this.productService.someFunction();
```

But if you don't want to import the product module in Store Module, you can make the Product Module a global Module -
https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#global-modules